# How I trigger a method after a assign attribute was updated of model

Tags: ruby

```
files = Dir.new("F:/data/").entries.grep(/.*_communities_.*.dat/) || []
fp = File.new(f, "r")
fp.close
File.delete(f)
```

doesn't work 
and i also try `DEL #{file}`
or
`system("DEL #{file}")`
 It don't work too

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I took the liberty of fixed up the formatting.  For next time, you can format your code by highlighting it and clicking on the "1010101" button.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to just delete all files in `/data` that match the Ruby regex `/.*_communities_.*\.dat/`?

For this you could use the [Dir.[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M002323) method along with a shell regex:

```
Dir['/data/*_communities_*.dat'].each do |file|
   File.delete file
end
```